# Change state in one Widget from another widget

Tags: flutter, stream, bloc

I'm programming a flutter application in which a user is presented with a PageView widget that allows him/her to navigate between 3 "pages" by swiping.

I'm following the setup used in https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-app-architecture-101-vanilla-scoped-model-bloc-7eff7b2baf7e, where I use a single class to load data into my model, which should reflect the corresponding state change (IsLoadingData/HasData).

I have a main page that holds all ViewPage widgets. The pages are constructed in the MainPageState object like this:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    _setBloc = SetBloc(widget._repository);
    _notificationBloc = NotificationBloc(widget._repository);
    leftWidget = NotificationPage(_notificationBloc);
    middleWidget = SetPage(_setBloc);
    currentPage = middleWidget;
    super.initState();
  }
```

If we go into the NotificationPage, then the first thing it does is attempt to load data:

```
      NotificationPage(this._notificationBloc) {
        _notificationBloc.loadNotificationData();
      }

which should be reflected in the build function when a user directs the application to it:

  //TODO: Consider if state management is correct
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<NotificationState>(
      stream: _notificationBloc.notification.asBroadcastStream(),
      //initialData might be problematic
      initialData: NotificationLoadingState(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data is NotificationLoadingState) {
          return _buildLoading();
        }
        if (snapshot.data is NotificationDataState) {
          NotificationDataState state = snapshot.data;
          return buildBody(context, state.notification);
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

What happens is that the screen will always hit "NotificationLoadingState" even when data has been loaded, which happens in the repository:

```
  void loadNotificationData() {
    _setStreamController.sink.add(NotificationState._notificationLoading());
    _repository.getNotificationTime().then((notification) {
      _setStreamController.sink
          .add(NotificationState._notificationData(notification));
      print(notification);
    });
  }
```

The notification is printed whilst on another page that is not the notification page.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
//....

class _SomeState extends State<SomeWidget> {

 //....
 Stream<int> notificationStream;
 //....

 @override
  void initState() {
   //....
    notificationStream = _notificationBloc.notification.asBroadcastStream()
    super.initState();
  } 

    //....
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<NotificationState>(
      stream: notificationStream,
     //....
```

Save your Stream somewhere and stop initialising it every time.
I suspect that the build method is called multiple times and therefore you create a new stream (initState is called once).

Please try let me know if this helped.

Comment: I'm investigating the issues, as I think you are right in the fact that multiple streams are being created, but i can't seem to have it work properly. For example, if i check the state of my notification page in my main page, then the main page will answer that there is data. The notification page will however just keep on loading as if it did not have data.